# Displaying pop up error message

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, message

I have a project where I need to enhance a given website. In the login page i have two fields (Username & password) and would like to display an error message in a pop up window if the user inputs wrong credentials.Was Thinking to do this in javascript The code i have till now is :

```
if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
    echo '<p id="err_msg">Oops! There was a problem:<br>';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) { 
        echo " - $msg<br>"; 
    }
    echo 'Please try again or <a href="register.php">Register</a></p>' ;
}
```

Comment: insted of echo use alert("Something")

Comment: @LazyDeveloper I think that is PHP code. So `echo` works fine and `alert` won't.

Comment: ohh then you need to add script tag and show alert

ex: echo '<script>alert("Error message")</script>'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. If you do the validation server side then you can guarantee the content is whats expected. You could use something like the following. Then set a timeout to hide the box if required.

```
<?php 

$sError = '';
$sEmail = '';


// if email posted check/validate 
if(isset($_POST['Email']) && $_POST['Email'] != ''){
    if(valid_email($_POST['Email'])){
        $sEmail = $_POST['Email'];
    }else{
        $sError .= "[InvalidEmail]";
    }
}

// if email is blank after validation, add to error string
if($sEmail == '') $sError .= "[Email]";



// then print using php 
if($sError !== ''){

    if( strpos($sError, '[Email]') !== false ||
        strpos($sError, '[Password]' ) !== false
    ){
        echo"<div class=\"statusMessage alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\"><ul>";

        if(strpos($sError, '[Email]') !== false){
            echo "<li>Please enter an email address</li>";
        }
        if(strpos($sError, '[InvalidEmail]') !== false){
            echo "<li>Email provided is invalid</li>";
        }

        echo "</ul></div>";
    }
}
?>
```